# Make number of optional parameters the same in a typesafe way

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make the number of optional arguments the same in Typescript?

In the example code a function has two (optional) arguments and the same arguments to the method. Is there a way to make the number of optional arguments the same in a typesafe way?

```
function withGood<A, T1, T2>(
  fn: (
    v1?: T1,
    v2?: T2,
  ) => A,
  v1?: T1,
  v2?: T2,
): A {

    return 
      fn(
        value(v1),
        value(v2),
      );
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYCgBmBXZAY0nlWVF1VQB4AxUTAD0k2QBNpQAKAOn4CG6RNABcoAcgCeAbQC6ASlABeAHwTpq7rmTi6AGlD9eQkeIAKQ0gIA2NS+gEBbTK3TR6q1UoDeoAL7YeIQkZBQARkLcAuLI+E7hmOiG4eLQkOjwyIi+AUEgoAButvDsoPjQAoiY0EFUqNyRyaAAjIYA5C3tCgDcddSNQoYtvf0NTaPYBcwADpgkjOjoGEF4A03DHV0dAuzs8KTktqAzQs6uSd19a+NDrYYZ+JijQA) what you're looking for? It is hard to tell from provided example, could you minimize it to showcase specific problem and remove all not relevant stuff?

Comment: A [mcve] as described in [ask] would greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer.  Ideally the code could be dropped as-is into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it would demonstrate the issue you're facing. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks minimized example. I wanted to give more context but you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type function's parameters in the following way: first parameter is a function and [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameter is restricted to parameters of the passed function:

```
function foo<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: F, ...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> { 
    return fn(...args);
}

function bar(a: number, b?: string) { }

// valid usages

foo(bar, 1, '1');

foo(bar, 1); // optional parameter remains optional

// expect error

foo(bar); // missing required parameter

foo(bar, 1, '1', 'additional parameter'); // not expected extra parameter

foo(bar, 1, true); // wrong type of parameter
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AxRBTAHlbMAEwGdEAKAOmoEMAnAcxIC5EawBPAbQF0BKRAF4AfG07DywMKwwAaRNUr0mrAAr0aAW2wE6JTML6sASjpB0wAFQ4AHbAcQBvRAChE7xHTMXkYKrUYSPgBuFwBfFxdQSFgERAAjenIaVjAQTXjsOnl4gH5WEig6GDAGAWcIlwB6KsQANxoAGxgiRBASGgZsEkiUOHJE7MQARnkAcmGxkN7UAfp5YZDEGsQ4G1iwJsQbDW1dT2xNGhKyNY2myJW8O2gcOjo4Ohn+waWVzRgSEhKGA4BHEAwLytHZ0LQ6LLPOZDUaICZjcY0IhEGDnRrbXYQuhTYLLWpgOBQHC4HbQbCtPBFGgYsF7SFRWaDBbyIogbBvWoAdwepUQUFs2FWwBp4N0LiAA)